# Modificador de acesso "private" em TypeScript

Tags: java, angular, typescript

Na maioria dos exemplos que encontro de TypeScript vejo que os atributos da classe não utilizam o modificador de acesso `private`. É uma questão de *design* ou há alguma diferença no funcionamento em relação ao Java?

```
export class Aluno {
    codigo:number;
    nome:string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos combinar que [o termo atributo está errado, você quer dizer campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). TypeScript tem seus membros públicos por padrão, então na falta de algo explícito o acesso é geral.

O fato de você não ver usarem `private` é só uma coincidência, é possível. Há uma corrente que não segue essa moda do "orientado a objeto" que tudo tem que ser privado, mesmo que as pessoas nem entendem porque estão fazendo isto. TS é uma linguagem de *script*, como o próprio nome diz, então é bem menos necessário seguir regras de orientação a objeto do que em outras linguagens. Mas se tiver um bom motivo pode estabelecer que qualquer membro seja privado.

É um pouco diferente do Java, que por sinal as pessoas acham que é privado por padrão e não é.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Conceptual.md).